# maven Liquibase error FATAL: password authentication failed for user

Tags: postgresql, maven, authentication, passwords, liquibase

Posting this since any of the past posts related to this topic didnt work for me.
tried almost every post related to this issue available in SOF

## Brief background

I had recently upgraded from Ubuntu 12.01 to 14.04.
I was having an development environment running perfectly fine with 12.01.

Maven build with LIquibase goal used to work fine till 12.01. this has started after 14.04 upgrade only.

The environment had Postgres 9.1 with 12.01
after upgrade, ubuntu also installed 9.3 as 9.1 was no longer supported.

I am facing couple of issues after the postgres installation.
Currently I am having both the versions active in the latest 14.04 version.

## Current Issue:

- When trying to build my Java Project with Maven command I am getting

  [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.0.5:update (default) on project XXX-web: Error setting up or running Liquibase: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "xxx"

## Things Tried

a. changed pg_hba.conf to md5, trust and password from ident but didnt work. here is the content of my pg_hba.conf of (9.1):

```
# Database administrative login by UNIX sockets
local   all         postgres                         trust

# TYPE  DATABASE    USER        CIDR-ADDRESS          METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
#local   all         all                               ident
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32         password
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all         all         ::1/128              password
# This is for general access databases:
local   all         all                               trust
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/0           trust
```

b. Checked the postgresql.conf file as well for listen_address = '*, localhost'

brief copy of postgresql.conf (9.1)

```
# - Connection Settings -

listen_addresses = '*,localhost'                # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                                        # comma-separated list of addresses;
                                        # defaults to 'localhost', '*' = all
                                        # (change requires restart)
port = 5432                             # (change requires restart)
```

c. checked all the relevant pom.xml. pom.xml's contain the required user and password details and also the connections to the postgres for Liquibase to execute or connect to the database.

d. also tried to connect through psql command prompt.

```
psql -d db -U user
```

works fine! no issues here

after these settings i had run

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql reload
```

also

```
restarted the postgres instances (service postgres restart)
```

but no luck!

did the same to 9.3 version files as well.

Can anyone help me guide as to where am I missing or tread me to correct path?

thanks in advance

Comment: can you connect locally? `psql` on the server?..

Comment: Yes.. I am able to connection locally with psql command.. psql -d db -U user works flawlessly fine..

Comment: `show hba_file ;` please - check if it is the file you edited

Comment: Yes correct.. it is the same file .. show hba_file;
               hba_file               
--------------------------------------
 /etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf

Comment: now run in same psql `alter user xxx password 'your_password' to make sure the password is correct, and then `psql  -d db -U xxx -h 127.0.0.1` - it should ask you for the password (cos it will hit the password rule before trust one)

Comment: did both the tasks. and its logs in well.. without giving any issues. btw thanks for your help till now. What else could be the reason?

Comment: so now - If you can connect with that password with psql on same IP, then you either connect to different cluster or provide different password

Comment: this operation is to build the java code with Liquibase. and the database settings should remain intact with the same cluster and password. otherwise it may fail in next steps. hope i understood your point well.. this is what you wanted me to do.. right?

Comment: no - I wanted you to make sure java connects to the same db with same credentials as you did. because it doesn't

Comment: single java program was also able to connect. but now I ran the mvn with -X option, and from the trace I found that the password was taking extra trailing letter "}".. not sure how it did enter in the code. but after removing it worked.. it works now.. your advice did help me to point me to look in where I should have looked. thanks a ton for your help and time!

Comment: sure. my pleasure.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Closing it and is it works now. 
Pls refer the last comment for the final answer on this issue.

Comment: Last comment didn't help: "sure. my pleasure." :P :D